# How to access detail from core-signal event in polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am working on a web app in polymer.dart. When I use core-signal, I am unable to access the detail. Here's some of the code that I'm using...

main_app.dart

```
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  onClick(Event event, var detail, Node sender) {
    print('button clicked');
    fire("core-signal",  detail:{'name':'button-click', 'data':0});
  }

  ready() { 
    super.ready();
  }
}
```

canvasContainer.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_signals.html">

<polymer-element name="canvas-container">
  <div>
    <template>
      <core-signals on-core-signal-button-click="{{testAction}}"></core-signals>
      <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
  <script type="application/dart" src="canvasContainer.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

canvasContainer.dart

```
class CanvasContainer extends PolymerElement {
 // more code up here, but irrelevent
 testAction(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
    print('event has been received');
    print(detail);
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(1000, 1000);
    context.stroke();
  }
}
```

MainApp receives the button click, and sends the "core-signals" event.
In the canvasContainer though, the event does get received, but when I print the detail, it just says "0". Any insight into the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way core-signal works, the `data` key of your detail object is what actually gets set as the `detail` of the event. The `name` property is then used to build the event type (it will be `core-signal-$name`).

See the docs here https://github.com/Polymer/core-signals/blob/master/core-signals.html#L79